# What is the role of 在 in 您要在关闭文件前保存吗？

Tags: mandarin, sentence-structure

I was using a text editor in Chinese, when I tried to exit without saving the currently opened  file it showed me this sentence:

> 您要在关闭文件前保存吗？

What is the role of 在 here? Is it related to the usage of `(some event)前`? Or can be omitted without altering the sentence meaning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is part of the construction:

> 在....前
> 'before....' (used as a conjunction).

Here it means '**Before** you close the file, do you want to save it?' The 在 effectively indicates a point in time, i.e., 'at' a particular time. (Literally translated into English, this would become 'at [the time] before you close the file').

This is typical of constructions like:

> 在...前
> 'before'
>
> 在...时
> 'when'
>
> 在...后
> 'after'
>
> 当...时
> 'when'

This tends to be a written usage and is omitted in conversation (and often in writing).